# Can the arrow on an XYPointerAnnotation be removed or changed to another shape?

Tags: java, annotations, jfreechart

I'm using XYPointerAnnotations on a chart, which are great, I'm just wondering if it's at all possible to change the arrow at the end of the pointer to another shape or to just remove the arrow. Maybe there's a different kind of annotation I could use? I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried changing "the tip radius and the base radius attributes?"

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can tell that just determines the length of the line with the arrow on it and how far away from my line it appears (setTipRadius(0.0) puts it directly on my vertical marker lines currently as I have it set up. setTipRadius(1.0) moves it left a bit, etc).

Is there more to these methods that I don't understand?

Comment: Not that I know; you can always do your own [`draw()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYPointerAnnotation.html#line.377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching and experimenting, I've found no evidence that the arrow pointer can be changed for the XYPointerAnnotation. Using XYTextAnnotations and rotating them combined with drawing your own lines and shapes can give similar results, but this is more involved and not as simple as making an XYPointerAnnotation. I've elected just to keep the pointer arrows in my chart.